# Cannot find the Vector<T>(Span<T>) constructor

Tags: c#, .net, system.numerics

I'm giving a try to SIMD in c# and trying to initialize a Vector from a Span ( `var myVector = new Vector<T>(myTSpan);`) as promised in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netstandard-2.1

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, C# 7.3; targeting to .NET Framework 4.7.2.
I'm using the System.Numerics 4.0.0.0, System.Numerics.Vectors 4.1.4.0 from NuGet, and System.Memory 4.0.1.0

I have also downloaded the NETStandard.Library 2.0.3  from NuGet and set the PackageReference Option but still cannot find it (I only get constructors from managed arrays).

What am I missing?

Comment: On that MSDN link it says `.NET Standard 2.1 Preview`. That might be the case