# System.Numerics.Vector<T> Initialization Performance on .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, simd, system.numerics

System.Numerics.Vector brings SIMD support to .NET Core and .NET Framework. It works on .NET Framework 4.6+ and .NET Core.

```
// Baseline
public void SimpleSumArray() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < left.Length; i++)
        results[i] = left[i] + right[i];
}

// Using Vector<T> for SIMD support
public void SimpleSumVectors() 
{
    int ceiling = left.Length / floatSlots * floatSlots;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ceiling; i += floatSlots)
    {
        Vector<float> v1 = new Vector<float>(left, i);
        Vector<float> v2 = new Vector<float>(right, i);
        (v1 + v2).CopyTo(results, i);
    }
    for (int i = ceiling; i < left.Length; i++)
    {
        results[i] = left[i] + right[i];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the initialization of the Vector can be the limiting step. To work around this, several sources recommend using MemoryMarshal to transform the source array into an array of Vectors [1][2]. For example:

```
// Improving Vector<T> Initialization Performance
public void SimpleSumVectorsNoCopy() 
{
    int numVectors = left.Length / floatSlots;
    int ceiling = numVectors * floatSlots;
    // leftMemory is simply a ReadOnlyMemory<float> referring to the "left" array
    ReadOnlySpan<Vector<float>> leftVecArray = MemoryMarshal.Cast<float, Vector<float>>(leftMemory.Span);
    ReadOnlySpan<Vector<float>> rightVecArray = MemoryMarshal.Cast<float, Vector<float>>(rightMemory.Span);
    Span<Vector<float>> resultsVecArray = MemoryMarshal.Cast<float, Vector<float>>(resultsMemory.Span);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVectors; i++)
        resultsVecArray[i] = leftVecArray[i] + rightVecArray[i];
}
```

This brings a dramatic improvement in performance **when running on .NET Core**:

```
|                 Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|----------------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|
|         SimpleSumArray | 165.90 us | 0.1393 us | 0.1303 us |
|       SimpleSumVectors |  53.69 us | 0.0473 us | 0.0443 us |
| SimpleSumVectorsNoCopy |  31.65 us | 0.1242 us | 0.1162 us |
```

Unfortunately, on **.NET Framework**, this way of initializing the vector has the opposite effect. It actually leads to worse performance:

```
|                 Method |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|----------------------- |----------:|---------:|---------:|
|         SimpleSumArray | 152.92 us | 0.128 us | 0.114 us |
|       SimpleSumVectors |  52.35 us | 0.041 us | 0.038 us |
| SimpleSumVectorsNoCopy |  77.50 us | 0.089 us | 0.084 us |
```

Is there a way to optimize the initialization of Vector on .NET Framework and get similar performance to .NET Core? Measurements have been performed using this sample application [1].

[1] https://github.com/CBGonzalez/SIMDPerformance

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/62702334/430935

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/issues/2581 "The .NET Framework runtime/JIT is not aware of span", so you shouldn't expect MemoryMarshal t yield better results.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies the results. So the span code falls back to a generic, portable implementation which is slow and does not achieve what the same code achieves on .NET Core: To re-interpret the array as an array of vectors, without making a copy. Is there any solution, perhaps a different trick, that can be used to improve performance on .NET Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the only efficient way to load a vector in .NET Framework 4.6 or 4.7 (presumably this will all change in 5.0) is with unsafe code, for example using `Unsafe.Read<Vector<float>>` (or its unaliged variant if applicable):

```
public unsafe void SimpleSumVectors()
{
    int ceiling = left.Length / floatSlots * floatSlots;

    fixed (float* leftp = left, rightp = right, resultsp = results)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ceiling; i += floatSlots)
        {
            Unsafe.Write(resultsp + i, 
                Unsafe.Read<Vector<float>>(leftp + i) + Unsafe.Read<Vector<float>>(rightp + i));
        }
    }
    for (int i = ceiling; i < left.Length; i++)
    {
        results[i] = left[i] + right[i];
    }
}
```

This uses the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` package which you can get via NuGet, but it could be done without that too.

Comment: That's a great solution. It delivers almost the same performance on .NET Framework as on .NET Core (at least on the benchmark from the question). Naive Vector initialization takes 52µs on both. The "Span" approach runs in 31µs on .NET Core, and the Unsafe.Read way takes 34µs on .NET Framework.